STM32: CMake seems to add Windows libraries when linking
I am trying to setup a CMake project for STM32 with FreeRtos and CMSIS. Compiling goes fine but when linking there are some errors, excerpt below:
 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ." c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--major-image-version'
Somehow the Linker configuration seems based on Windows instead of ARM.
It is not obvious from where those Windows libraries are added. This applies to 'major-image-version' as well (searching only finds it in the build directory, not in the source directory) For this reason it seems CMake adds it.
Any suggestion where this comes from ?

Can you post your toolchain file? It seems like CMake is initializing the linker flags to some default for Windows, and I wonder if the toolchain file is not setting CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT

Actually I was using QtCreator and didn't use a toolchain file. In QtCreator the toolchain is configured using a 'kit' and it sets some variables ( CMAKE_C_COMPILER, CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER) After your question for a toolchain file, I decided to give it a try from a Windows command prompt using a toolchain file.  It built without any problems. Still unclear to me why not using QtCreator, since the toolchain file does not contain much special. I will try to find out where the different behavior comes from.

To answer my own question:
It built successful using a toolchain file. After this, I tried to find out which of the statements in the toolchain file caused the aforementioned linking behavior to disappear.
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
It was already in my CMakelist.txt file.  Moving it to the top of the file solved the issue.
